# Condition for Armstrong number

Tags: python-2.7

Can anybody tell me what is wrong with  my code for checking whether a number is an Armstrong number?

```
n=input('Enter the number=')
m=n
s=0
while n>0:
    d=n%10
    s=s+d**3
    n=n*10
if m==s:
    print'The number is an Armstrong number'
else:
    print'The number is not an Armstrong number'
```

Comment: what do you expect to happen? What is happening instead? If you get errors, these are crucial to helping you, obviously.

Comment: I am trying to break down the number into its constituent digits but this is not happening. As for the errors, it is not showing any error statement but is running infinitely.

Comment: @Marcus Müller Thanks for the comment anyways. It made me rethink the whole thing logically again:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the program to work eventually. Turns out I had kept typing the statement `n=n/10` as `n=n*10`. Mistakes do happen sometimes:)

```python
n = input('Enter the number=')
m = n
s = 0
while n>0:
    d = n%10
    s += d**3
    n /= 10
if m==s:
    print'The number is an Armstrong number'
else:
    print'The number is not an Armstrong number'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sum = 0
no = int(raw_input("Enter the the number to check it is armstrong on or not :"))
pow_no = len(str(no))
check = no

print "#################Method -I Result##############"
while 0<no:
  sum = sum +((no%10)**pow_no)
  no = no / 10
if check == sum:
  print "%s is Armstrong"%check
else:
  print "%s is not Armstrong"%check

print "################Method -II Result#############"
for i in str(no):
  sum = sum + (int(i)**pow_no)
if check == sum:
  print "%s is Armstrong"%check
else:
  print "%s is not Armstrong"%check
```